# Can AEM 6.2 be enhanced to support webp?

Tags: aem, webp

We need to support webp images in AEM 6.2. 
As this is not supported by default, is there a possibility to enhance AEM by adding and rendering a new mime type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a workflow process step to do this along with a Java WebP library such as webp-imageio [0], then add this step to your default asset workflow (usually update_asset) so they are created along with the standard web/thumb renditions.

Alternatively you can convert them offline ad-hoc and upload as a custom rendition if you only need them for a few assets.

[0] https://bitbucket.org/luciad/webp-imageio

Comment: Would that enable ootb image components to handle webp files (dropzones and more) or would webp images be rendered correctly if they were referenced in the html? i don't think so.

Comment: @OliverGebert I believe it would depend on the brower's support for WebP. Currently it's supported in Chrome, Edge, Firefox, and most Android browsers, but notably not yet in iOS or macOS Safari.

Ref: https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp